# equals(...) and equalsIgnoreCase(...)

Tags: java

Why do we have `equals()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()` as two different methods, when `equals()` could have been overloaded with a special `ignoreCase` argument to provide `equalsIgnoreCase()` functionality?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The method `equals()` is inherited from `Object`, so its signature should not be changed. `equals()` can often be used without actually knowing the concrete class of the object, e.g. when iterating through a collection of objects (especially before Java 5 generics). So then you wouldn't even see the other `equals()` without downcasting your object to `String` first.

This was a design choice from the creators of Java to make the idiom of using `equals()` usable exactly the same way for all objects.

Moreover, IMO

```
if (string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)) ...
```

is more readable, thus less error-prone than

```
if (string1.equals(string2, true)) ...
```

Of course, in your own classes you are free to add an `equals()` with different signature (on top of the standard `equals()`, that is).

Comment: but I see other implementations such as `compareTo()` and `compareToIgnoreCase()` as well, which have got no connection with `Object` class per se.

Comment: @Vaibhav A good API design is consistent with naming (among other things). If methods doing similar things are named according to a similar pattern, the API is easier to learn and use, which also reduces the chance of errors. Moreover, my readability argument above applies to `compareToIgnoreCase()` as well as `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 3):

`equalIgnoreCase()` is used for ignore the Case sensitive of our `String`. But the `equals()` is only returns `true`, while be same case of `string`

ex,

```
String value="java";
if(value.equals("JAva")
{
    System.out.println("Return True");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Return False");
}
```

Ans: Returns `False`

but the other one is,

```
if(value.equalIgnoreCase("JAva")
{
    System.out.println("Return True");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Return False");
}
```

Ans: Returns `True`

Comment: Please read and UNDERSTAND the question before posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible to do what you are suggesting but the language designers chose to go the other way and hence we have `equalsIgnoreCase(otherString)` instead of say `equals(otherString, StringConstants.IGNORE_CASE)` or `equals(otherString, true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `equals()` method is inherited from Object.

If they did it as you suggest then we would have something like this:

```
public final class String {

    public boolean equals () { ... }

    public boolean equals (boolean ignoreCase) { ... }

}
```

And without reading documentation it would be impossible to understand what method `equals()` (which without parameter) do.

Comment: That's a perfectly common API pattern. The first form uses a default value for the argument. And if it's impossible to tell what that default is without reading the documentation, then you read the documentation.

Comment: OK, `java.lang.String` has several constructors, many of which are simpler versions of other constructors, and supply default values when they call them. The behaviour is not obvious without looking at the javadoc.

Comment: @skaffman: you see, boolean is not an integer, for example, thus there are only 2 values: `true` or `false`. If we have default value `false` then the only reason to use another method is to pass `true` as a parameter. If it always true, then from point of view of API design it's much better to create separate method with meaningful name (i.e. equalsIgnoreCase). Yes, this approach gives us less flexibility but it's a rare case when we need to get value of `ignoreCase` from the outside. Usually it's predefined by some business logic rules.

Answer (score 1):

The main test when overridng a method with additional parameters is that I would expect any method override to do exactly the same thing as the method it's overriding. Equals(), being derived from Object has a contract it must follow. Two objects that are equal() should have identical hashcodes. I don't think two objects that are case insensitive equal should have the same hashcode, so I believe overriding equal here is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think they just chose one of the alternatives. .NET chose the other.
StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase etc.

Definitely what you are suggesting and [even better what] .NET implemented would have been more flexible for different cultures etc. In fact I don't even know what culture they use in this ignore case. I guess Current culture.