# Difference between matches and equalsIgnoreCase or equals in string class

Tags: java, string, equals

**matches**: Will check if the complete string entered is equal to the value present in the string object.

**equalsIgnoreCase**: Ignoring the case, it checks if the string entered is equal to the value present in the string object.

**equals**: Case sensitive and it checks if the string entered is equal to the value present in the string object.

This is what I know about the methods, present in String class.

Are there any other differences(Am I missing any valuable differences)?

If there are no differences, then why cant matches method be removed from String class, since the functionality it puts forth can be achieved using the other above mentioned methods, appropriately.

Comment: [matches](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/string_matches.shtml) works on regular expressions.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483029/equals-and-equalsignorecase)

Comment: Sorry but am not confused between equals and equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: @Ajj:) You may be confusing about regular expressions. A regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to "match" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters. Abbreviations for "regular expression" include "regex" and "regexp". In simple words, *a regular expression defines a pattern that matches a certain set of strings.*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a big difference - [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) checks the match of a `String` to a regular expression pattern, not the same string. Do not be mislead by the fact that it receives a `String` as an argument.

For example:

```
"hello".equals(".*e.*"); // false
"hello".matches(".*e.*"); // true
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? Am unable to make the difference.

Comment: What is .* which you are using here ??

Comment: This is a wildcard. Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: @Ajj Unless you know what a regular expression is, The answer isn't going to make much sense.

Comment: Thank you. Will go through wildcards

Comment: * on both sides of the string means it will search for the string on where there are letters on either side.

Answer (score 14):

The key difference is that `matches` matches a regular expressions whereas equals matches a specific String.

```
System.out.println("hello".matches(".+"));    // Output: true
System.out.println("hello".equals(".+"));     // Output: false
System.out.println("wtf?".matches("wtf?"));   // Output: false
System.out.println("wtf?".equals("wtf?"));    // Output: true
```

I suggest you have a look at what a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is

Comment: Can you please tell me about .+   What is happening at run time ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I got from the documentation...

**matches** (`String regex`): Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression

**equals** (`String Object`): Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

**equalsIgnoreCase** (`String anotherString`): Compares this String to another String ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

`matches` returns true if the string matches a regular expression, therefore, it should not be removed from the String class.

Answer (score 0):

matches() used for verifying---- whether the given string matches to specified regexpression

ex.;String s = "humbapumpa jim";
        assertTrue(s.matches(".*(jim|joe).*"));

equals() for just checking the given string with specified string as exact match.
equalsIgnoreCase() --- will ignore the case sensitive.