# EditText always showing null

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

My xml

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/newPlaceLatLable"
        android:text="Place Latitude"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/newPlaceLable"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newPlaceLat"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newPlaceLatLable" 
         android:layout_below="@id/newPlaceLable"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/newPlaceLonLable"
        android:text="Place Longitude"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/newPlaceLatLable"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newPlaceLon"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newPlaceLonLable" 
        android:layout_below="@id/newPlaceLatLable"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />
```

and in code

```
if (et1.getText().toString().matches(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (et2.getText().toString().matches(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else  if (et3.getText().toString().matches(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

where et1, et2 and et3 are

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPlaceText);        
         et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPlaceLat);
         et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPlaceLon);
```

but every time i run app ,it gives toast "Latitute can't be null". Although et2 has text in it, but it didn't show it here. kindly look in it. what's problem

Comment: that is your complete xml code. Here show only two edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to check it the `EditText` are filled with same value.

```
matches("")
```

is not what you need.

Check if the `lenght` of the String is > 0, or use `equals("")`

```
if (et1.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (et2.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else  if (et3.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Still not working. Actullay et2.getText() is always blank , event it has text in it.

Comment: it can not be blank and at the same time has text.

Comment: I mean. when i enter text in app. This is wondering. as et1 shows it has text but et2 doesn't.

Comment: your last sentence does not make sense to me

Comment: I hope you are not using `et2 = new EditText(context);` anywhere inside your code, this will change the reference.. Just one Guess.....

Comment: My Mistake. It was a problem in xml with id. Sorry, for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with as **@blackbelt** suggested or like this..

```
if (et1.getText().toString().equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (et2.getText().toString().equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else  if (et3.getText().toString().equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
if (et1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (et2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else  if (et3.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitute can't be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

the difference between matches() & equal() is that matches() checks the match of a String to a regular expression pattern while the equal() Compares this Comparator with the specified Object and indicates whether they are equal, see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700152/2240535